# Braces error open cl code - using C++

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm following this tutorial: 
http://simpleopencl.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/tutorial-simple-start-with-opencl-and-c.html

and I got 3 errors:

ERROR 1) - solved

```
cl::Context context({default_device}); //original code
```

I just took off the braces and It's ok.

ERROR 2) - solved

```
if(program.build(default_device)!=CL_SUCCESS){
```

I just replace "default_device" for "all_devices" and It's ok.

ERROR 3) - not solved

```
sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});
```

I don't know what to do. Visual Studio is pointing this error message:
**"IntelliSense: expected an expression"**

Here is the piece of the code I'm talking about:

```
cl::Device default_device = all_devices[0];
std::cout<< "Using device: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<"\n";

cl::Context context(default_device);

cl::Program::Sources sources;

// kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
std::string kernel_code=
    "void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C)"
    "{"
    "C[get_global_id(0)]=A[get_global_id(0)]+B[get_global_id(0)];"
    "}";
sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});

cl::Program program(context,sources);
if(program.build(all_devices)!=CL_SUCCESS){
    std::cout<<" Error building: "<<program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)<<"\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last problem is the missing "pair"

```
std::string kernelFunctionToBeCompiled ...

sources.push_back(
                     std::make_pair(
                                      kernelFunctionToBeCompiled.data(),
                                      kernelFunctionToBeCompiled.length()
                                    )
                  );
```

Its opencl 1.2 bindings I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

```
sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});
```

Could be written as

```
sources.push_back(
    {
        kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()
    }
);
```

In between the curly brackets its expecting an expression, something that ends with `;`. Thats what your error is telling you.

Now i dont know how `Sources` is defined but here in these brackets

```
sources.push_back(...);
```

you have to specify a variable of whatever type `sources` consists of, so it can be added (pushed back)

This is an example of a `std::vector<int>` that consists of `int`s

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
myvector.push_back(42);
```

`Sources` probably works in a similar way

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: look in this image what push_back() is asking for:
http://pasteboard.co/DlUIdna.png

Comment: That gives me headaches